# How do you apply styling to a Ruby form tag?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bulma

I'd like to use Bulma styling from the following code snippet for a file upload button:

```html
<div class="file">
  <label class="file-label">
    <input class="file-input" type="file" name="resume">
    <span class="file-cta">
      <span class="file-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="file-label">
        Choose a file…
      </span>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

However, since I'm using a Rails form, the code I'm using for the file submission button is as follows:

```html
<div class="column">
    <%= label_tag :sample_file, 'Sample file' %>
    <%= file_field_tag :sample_file %>
</div>
```

I'm trying to apply the Bulma styling to this tag, and it generally works for buttons as I can simply reuse the Bulma class tag and add it to the Rails form snippet (i.e. this will work fine for submit tags). For some UI elements though, it just doesn't render. Does anyone know how I can apply these more complex stylings to Rails tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's *really* troubling you to put all the Bulma markup in your view. You can make a helper:

```html
<div class="column">
    <%= bulma_file_field_tag :sample_file, "Voters file" %>
</div>
```

and put all the Bulma markup into the helper

```rb
# in app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  def bulma_file_field_tag(name, label)
      <<-TAG.html_safe
      <div class="file">
        <label class="file-label">
          <input class="file-input" type="file" name="#{name}">
          <span class="file-cta">
            <span class="file-icon">
              <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="file-label">
              #{label}
            </span>
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    TAG
  end
```

Comment: This is not really good use of `html_safe` as it marks the entire string as safe. So if for example the name or label variables contain user provided content it could be a vector for an XSS injection attack. 
https://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-how-to-use-html_safe-correctly

Comment: @max, indeed, generally this could have vulnerabilities, but in this case the interpolations are just two string fields, defined by the coder, not a user. I don't see any risk. But, yes, if you're concerned, the link shows a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This makes sense. New to web dev, and wasn't sure about convention when it comes to mixing Rails form tags with full HTML blocks and all. Since it seems to not really be a big deal, I'll go with this for more complex form elements that don't recognize the Bulma class stylings.

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify `name` for your input and label text

And use plain HTML without any rails helper

```
<div class="file">
  <label class="file-label">
    <input class="file-input" type="file" name="sample_file"> <!-- name here -->
    <span class="file-cta">
      <span class="file-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="file-label">
        Voters file <!-- text here -->
      </span>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

That's it

Answer (score 1):

Most all the tag helpers for tags with content accept an optional block:

```
<%= label_tag :sample_file, 'Voters file', class: "file-label" do %>
  <!-- this will be the content of the label element -->
<% end %>
```

Although in this case its kind of questionable why you're even using the tag helper - you're not using a FormBuilder so its not providing any kind of functionality and a simple literal HTML tag would do the exact same job.